# Cannot control size/positon of Div within a Div

Tags: css, html, resize, position, stylesheet

I'm working on this project for an instagram search.  I get the results I want, and I want the main images to display with the small thumbnail of the user profile underneath the main photo, along with user name,etc.  Right now im working on just getting the main image with a small thumbnail of the user under the photo.  Right now all i get is the main photo and profile picture taking up the entire width of the div. I can't get it to move and the chrome developer tool shows thats completely ignoring my css for these sub-divs.

Here is the CSS snippet:

```
html {}
body { font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif; }

small { display: block; color: #555; padding: 10px 0px; }

#searchresults {  width: 960px; }

#sform { width: 710px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 35px; }
#sform #s { 
    padding: 10px 11px; 
    padding-left: 60px;
    color: #999; 
    width: 200px; 
    border: 1px solid #ddd; 
    font-size: 22px; 
.
.
.
.
#photos { margin-left: 100px; text-align: center; }

#box { width:180px;
    height:260px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-bottom:30px; }

#box .mainimg { width: 160px;
       height 230px; }

#box .footer { width: 180px;
      height: 30 px; }
```

and the HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="searchresults">
<section id="sform"><input autocomplete="off" class="sfield" id="s" name="s"    placeholder="Enter a search tag..." type="text" /></section>

<section id="photos"></section>
</div>
</body>
```

and the code that #each passes

```
    <div class="box"><div class="box.mainimg"><a href="'+data[i].url+'" target="_blank"><img src="'+data[i].thumb+'"></a></div><div class="box.footer"><img src="'+data[i].avatar+'"></div></div>'
```

Thanks in advance.  I can't seem to find this anywhere.

Comment: Adding div id="box" and  div id="box.mainimg" etc.. fixed the alignment issues.  However i still cannot resize those boxes at all.  The images are defaulting to 180x150. Any idea why its ignoring the CSS here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html you've assigned your box div a class, not an id - in the css your selectors point to a box id.

So

```
.box { width:180px;
    height:260px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-bottom:30px; }

.box .mainimg { width: 160px;
       height 230px; }

.box .footer { width: 180px;
      height: 30 px; }
```

Should fix it - or change the div to `id="box"`

Comment: Adding div id="box" and div id="box.mainimg" etc.. fixed the alignment issues. However i still cannot resize those boxes at all. The images are defaulting to 180x150. Any idea why its ignoring the CSS here? –

Comment: You need to add a selector for the images: `.box img {width: 180; height: 260;}` or whatever size it is you want.

Comment: since you've changed it #box img {} - also in the html you can just put class="mainimg" and because that div is within the box div you can call it with the #box .mainimg css selector

Comment: still no luck. again, the alignment is fine. Here is what i have now:

Comment: <div id="box"><div id="box.mainimg"><a href="'+data[i].url+'" target="_blank"><img src="'+data[i].thumb+'"></a></div><div id="box.footer"><img src="'+data[i].avatar+'"></div></div>

Comment: #photos { margin-left: 100px; text-align: center; }

#box { width:180px;
 height:260px;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-left:20px;
 margin-bottom:300px; }

#box .mainimg img { width: 160px;
    height auto; }

#box .footer img { position: relative; width: 80px;
   height: auto; }

Comment: Your ID's are still wrong, and should be classes. You should put `<div class="mainimg">` and `<div class="footer">` in your html. You won't need to change the css (`#box .mainimg img {}` etc. is correct) as the divs inherent the parent ID.

Answer (score 1):

**since you've changed it #box img {} - also in the html you can just put class="mainimg" and because that div is within the box div you can call it with the #box .mainimg css selector**

i re-read this and it worked. css is picky!!

Comment: css is very picky, glad I could help!